# Encryption on a Java based mobile

Tags: java-me

Could we doing call encryption on JAVA ME  mobile?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out the [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) library?

It's one of the most popular encryption libraries for Java, and it has a Lightweight API distribution for JavaME (as you can see at their [latest releases page](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html)).

Comment: I need to know could we implement Encryption alogrithm on java ME on mobile?